# Approve photo tags in facebook app for windows phone 8

Tags: 8.0, facebook

Do we have a timeline review or an activity log in WP8 Facebook app?

I have both apps, the normal facebook app and the facebook beta app. I have failed to find an answer to this. The notification shows I have been tagged in a photo, but tapping it does not do anything.

Currently, I log in through m.facebook.com and approve or do it on the PC.

Any heads up in this regard??

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is two-fold

1. At the time of writing (this answer), there is no way to be able to timeline review on the Windows Phone Facebook apps.
2. Point 1 above may well be out of date itself at some point in the future as Microsoft has stated that it is committed to developing a highly functional version of Facebook for mobile (hence the beta).

The alternative solutions you are currently using and your best bet for now!